# How can I combine two Future[JsArray]?

Tags: scala, future

I have two `Future[JsArray]`, `f1` and `f2`, and I need to wait that both are completed with a result.

If they both succeed, the final result should be a `Success` holding the sum of their contents. If at least one of then fails, the final result should be a `Failure`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## One solution

1. Define a `map2` function for `Future`s:

   ```scala
   def map2[A, B, C](fa: Future[A], fb: Future[B])(g: (A, B) => C)
                    (implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[C] =
     for {
       a <- fa
       b <- fb
     } yield g(a, b)
   ```
2. Define a `merge` function for merging the two `JsArray`s (i.e. extracting and concatenating the *elements*, and use the result to create a new `JsArray`):

   ```scala
   def merge(array1: JsArray, array2: JsArray): JsArray =
     JsArray(array1.elements ++ array2.elements: _*)
   ```

   Note: you need the type ascription in order to pass the resulting `Vector` to [`JsArray`'s `apply` method](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/master/src/main/scala/spray/json/JsValue.scala#L70).
3. Call

   ```scala
   map2(f1, f2)(merge)
   ```

## Trial run in the REPL

```
scala> import spray.json._
import spray.json._

scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> val f1 = Future(JsArray(JsNumber(1), JsNumber(2))) 
f1: scala.concurrent.Future[spray.json.JsArray] = List()

scala> val f2 = Future(JsArray(JsNumber(3), JsNumber(4), JsNumber(5)))
f2: scala.concurrent.Future[spray.json.JsArray] = List()

scala> map2(f1, f2)(merge).onComplete(println)
Success([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Comment: That creates an array of arrays, you might want `JsArray(jsArray1.elements ++ jsArray2.elements)`

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco Good point, and I'm guessing that's probably what the OP wants. I'll amend my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine futures using 'for' syntax. Something like:

```
val f1:Future[Int] = getF1()
val f2:Future[Int] = getF2()
val res:Future[Int] = for (
  v1 <- f1;
  v2 <- f2
) yield (v1 + v2)
```

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question. The type is not `Int` but `JsArray`. What I don't get is that the type of `res` is `Future[String]` instead of `Js*`.

Comment: How do us 'sum' JsArrays?

Comment: I don't know it. I was expecting `++`

Answer (score 3):

**Straight forward and simple solution**

Future supports `zip` operation which is very handy.

```
val f1: Future[JsArray]
val f2: Future[JsArray]
val resultF = f1.zip(f2).map {case (a, b) =>  a ++ b}
```

if `f1` or `f2` fails, `resultF` will also fail with the same exception of `f1` or `f2` failure.

optionally you could remove parenthesis

```
val resultF = f1 zip f2 map { case (f1Result, f2Result) => f1Result ++ f2Result }
```

Comment: I like the "zip" solution - thank you for the extra suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by "summing arrays" you mean concatenating them with `++`, you are looking to do:

```
Future.sequence(Set(getF1,getF2)) map { _ reduce(_ ++ _)}
```

The sequence will succeed if and only if all futures succeed. Then we reduce the resulting `Set` by `++`-ing all its elements.

Comment: it returns `value ++ is not a member of spray.json.JsArray`

Comment: I don't know what operation you are trying to achieve. Do you have an example? (if you already know what operation to apply you can just put it in place of `++`)